# TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, matrix-multiplication

How to fix `TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`? Not sure how to fix this error. Do not get what is means by 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

```
def minmult(n,d):
    m = [[0 for x in range(n)] for x in range(n)]
    s = [[0 for x in range(n)] for x in range(n)]

    for i in range(1, n):
        m[i][i] = 0
        s[i][i] = 0

    for diagonal in range(1, n-1):
        m[i][j] = sys.maxsize
        for i in range(n-diagonal):
            j=i+diagonal
            temp = m[i][k] + m[k+1][j] + d[i-1]*d[k]*d[j]
            if temp < m[i][j]:
                m[i][j] = q
                s[i][j]=k
    pprint(m)
    pprint(s)
    return m[1][n-1]

array=[10,4,5,20,2,50]
size = len(array)
print(str(minmult(array,size)))
```

Comment: Which line is the error on? You have more information than we do.

Comment: `n` is a `list`, and `range(n)` doesn't make sense.

Comment: we need more information on the problem

Answer (score 0):

The error is on this line:

```
m = [[0 for x in range(n)] for x in range(n)]
```

Since you passed in `n` to `minmult` as a list, and `range` expects an integer, you're getting an error.

As the comments say, and as your code is written, you want to change the call to:

```
minmult(size,array)
```

There's no reason to pass the size of the array as you can determine it within the function...

Comment: I think the arguments are being passed in the wrong order. `n` should be the length of the list, while `d` is the list itself. (Though, come to think of it, a More Pythonic approach would skip passing in the length at all if it can be deduced from the list.)

Comment: How would I fix that line then?

Comment: Answer updated based on @Blckknght's comments and your question.